# How do i know tabletop object detector uses what method to link the object recognition and the position together

Tags: ros, tabletop-object-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi could someone please tell me how http://wiki.ros.org/tabletop_object_detector link the object recognition and the position together. i don't quite understand the wiki.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194395/how-do-i-know-tabletop-object-detector-uses-what-method-to--link-the-object-recognition-and-the-position-together/) by [chiongsterx](https://answers.ros.org/users/19856/chiongsterx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it's not in the wiki, the next best place to look is the [code api](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/tabletop_object_detector/html/) and then the [source](https://github.com/ros-interactive-manipulation/pr2_object_manipulation/tree/groovy-devel/perception/tabletop_object_detector).

Since the input data is a pointcloud, the position will be likely obtained from the fundamental ROS concept of [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf), hence why it's probably not explicitly documented.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0